# Conditional based on external variable (not in-query)

Tags: node.js, joi

I need to check if role must be required or not based on externalVar's value. How can I achieve that?

```
const Joi = require('joi')

let externalVar = true

module.exports = Joi.object({
  username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
  password: Joi.string().pattern( /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30}$/ ).required(),

  // here
  role: Joi.number().when(externalVar, { is: false, then: Joi.required(), otherwise: null })
})
```

Comment: I get "Error: Invalid condition: false" at the line of "role"

Comment: Please put that information and anything else that's relevant in your quesiton.

Comment: And please don't tack tags onto your question title.

Comment: How about this - role: !externalVal? Joi.number().required() : Joi.number().optional()